# I need to build a custom function in a manager with field's value from a model

Tags: python, django, function, django-models

I'm trying to create a custom function in a model manager:

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    # Return body from last child message
    def get_last_child_body(self):
        if self.has_childs:
            last_child = self.filter(parent_msg=self.id).order_by('-send_at')[0]
            return last_child.body
```

I want to use this function ("get_last_child_body") in template

```
{% message.get_last_child_body %}
```

to retrieve the body from the last child message inserted in table message.

The Message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_messages')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='received_messages')
    parent_msg = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next_messages', null=True, blank=True)
    has_childs = models.BooleanField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body = models.TextField()
    send_at = models.DateTimeField()
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    replied_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sender_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    recipient_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = MessageManager()

    def get_last_child(self):
        if not self.has_childs:
            return None

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'send_at'
        ordering = ['-send_at']
```

Well, I'm guessing the problem is located in "id" from custom function in manager. I have to pass the  parent message id but i don't know how can i do it.

It does not report any error, it just does not show anything in template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think this should go in the Manager? Why not on the model, just like `get_last_child`?

Comment: To do this, i was looking for information in django documentation and around internet, and i don't know why but i thought this was the best way.

Was i wrong ?

Comment: Well, i made a try putting get_last_child_body on model like you said to me. It doesn't run.

Comment: "It doesn't run" - what does that even mean? What happened? What error did you get?

Comment: In template, it doesn't show anything. Like there was not a call to database or just database was empty. It just does not show the information from database.

There is not any error either.

Comment: I fixed your formatting for you.  Looks like you are indenting your python programs with TABs (which don't seem to display properly in stack overflow).  See spaces vs tabs in python here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2 to code in Python. It (in theory) changes tabs for 4 blank spaces. But making copy/paste not seem to work. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managers should be used for Model specific operators. Here however you are doing an instance specific operation so the `get_last_child_body` should be inside your `Message` class.

In comments you mentioned you tried to move it. It should work, something else is probably wrong. You should verify that:

1. message is defined in the template (use if template tag for example to log result )
2. get_last_child_body gets called (use print statements for example)
3. keep on debugging deeper is still no result (print statements work if it's easiest for you)

Comment: I have been checking all the code and i found the error. I was setting:

    `last_child = self.filter(parent_msg=self.id).order_by('-send_at')[0]`

Instead:

`last_child = Message.objects.filter(parent_msg=self.id).order_by('-send_at')[0]`

Now, it works. Thanks all for your answers!